# How do I include a previous version of Google Font from Google's Font Library

Tags: google-fonts

I am using Material Icons directly from Google's CDN.
https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons
But some recent changes made my icons show a bit differently.
`src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v51/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNcIhQ8tQ.woff2) format('woff2');`
It looks like they have released a new version of the font - version 5.
How can I include the previous version from Googl'e CDN ?